# Proving the size of the conjugacy class $x^G$ is given by $|x^G| = \frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I am reading a textbook and am confused of the proof of the following theorem:

> Let $x\in G$. The size of the conjugacy class $x^G$ is given by $$|x^G| = \frac{|G|}{|C_G(x)|}$$  where $C_G(x)$ is the set of elements of $G$ commuting with $x$; that is, $$C_G(x)=\{g\in G: xg= gx\}.$$

The first part of proof goes as the following:

For $g$, $h\in G,$ we have $$g^{-1}xg = h^{-1}xh \Longleftrightarrow hg^{-1}x=xhg^{-1} \Longleftrightarrow hg^{-1}\in C_G(x) \Longleftrightarrow C_G(x)g = C_G(x)h$$

My question is how to get the last step; i.e., $C_G(x)g = C_G(x)h$?

Note: The textbook is "Representations and Characters of Group (G. James & M. Liebeck) p.107"

Comment: That's a standard property of cosets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$hg^{-1}$ in $C$ implies $h$ in $Cg$, which implies $Ch=Cg$.

Comment: Now I know $h\in Cg$. However, I am still confused about "$Ch=Cg$". How to get there?  I still miss that one step.

Comment: Well, $h$ is also in $Ch$, right? And two cosets are either disjoint or equal, right?

Comment: I get the point, thanks!